# Sending an email from my ROR4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I know the question has been asked before, but I still can't get it to work, even though the console is saying it has.

emailer.rb

```
    class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"



  def welcome_email()

      @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
      email_with_name = "#{My Name} <#{MyEmail@gmail.com}>"
      mail(to: email_with_name, subject: 'Test')
  end

end
```

environment.rb #(in config)

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'example.com',
    user_name:            'myemail@gmail.com',
    password:             'mypassword',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

To test, I'm putting `Emailer.welcome_email().deliver` into the console

I'm told that if my setting are incorrect, it's possible that no error comes up.

Do these settings look ok to everyone? If so, where else might I check to find the problem?

Thanks

Comment: what are you seeing in `log/development.log`? this blog post might be helpful for you http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you. All the data appeared to be passing through but no email was getting sent. I was actually seeing a Connection error in my server log which to me indicated an inability of my app to connect to Google.

I ended up finding this instruction set http://www.leemunroe.com/send-automated-email-ruby-rails-mailgun/ and creating a free MailGun account. It was really straight-forward. Had it up and running within about 30 minutes, as opposed to the hours I spent failing with Google + SMTP.

Hope this helps. Good luck.